# CSS of page(height,width) appears smaller than what it actually must be

Tags: javascript, html, css, reveal.js

I am using a [reveal.js code](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/).

The code works perfectly fine in my local pc as well as [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Mau5/)

But the moment i put the code in my website.the width and height of the content changes from 1000px to 200px.

If I use inspect element...it says the width of the container is about 600-1000px...but if we see it visually it appears only 200px.If I change the number to some larger number,say 4000px,it changes to only max 300px.

Somehow whatever content I put it appears minified.

Here is my [website](http://facebook.ilovetrolls.org/2014/02/11-reasons-why-i-love-trolls-is-best_35.html#/)  and working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Mau5/)

I am stuck on the this thing since past 2 days,inspect element is not helping

The basic code for CSS is

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden
}
.reveal .slides {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    overflow:visible;
```

Edit:After much research,I found out,that apart from the height,width issue,various transitions are not working...there is something disturbing the js code

Comment: Your half of the HTML document is filled with CSS, consider shifting them to another css file

Comment: Remove `zoom: 0.2;` from CSS

Comment: You have invalid markup as well http://i.stack.imgur.com/0pagO.png

Comment: Sorry, there is no zoom in css, but it gets added via javascript on the `.slides` element.

Comment: @IgorJerosimić cant find :( where is it?

Comment: @Mr.Alien corrected :),in vain..hmmmm

Comment: @Michel [http://oi59.tinypic.com/6sz3vk.jpg](http://oi59.tinypic.com/6sz3vk.jpg)

Comment: In jsfiddle it is working probably because it's not the same code. There must some kind of interference between the different external files.
E.g.: Search the CSS files for equal selectors.

Comment: apart from the height,width issue, various transitions are not working...there is something disturbing disurbing the js code at the bottom..i am trying to troubleshoot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Removed**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and it worked.Don't know logic,but i am glad its working now.

Comment: Bad solution. You need that to follow HTML standards. However, if you're not using HTML5, then you might just need to use a different DOCTYPE.

Answer (score 0):

just add this line to your `.reveal .slides` css class

```
zoom: 1 !important;
```